# Exporting data from BigQuery into a local PostgreSQL/MySql database

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm BigQuery and the Python API for BigQuery - virgin.

My task is: pull data from the [google open dataset](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-natality) **using BigQuery and Python API**, load the data into the MySql/PostgreSQL local database (the one installed on my PC)

The way i see it (after my 2-hour research) is:
pull data into a local csv file ([using this kind of a sample code](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple)), load the data from the file into the database.

Does this resemble the right way of performing the task?

If not, could you please provide some advice/instruction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the right way to do.

Comment: Can it be done omitting the csv file step? SOrt of on-the-go?

Comment: You could run the query and process the output https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults But exporting into CSV would speed up the import into your SQL database.

Comment: I've sort of already done it. Now i'm going to polish it off and i'll post the solution here. Because there is no such solution on the internet atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The API method**

The steps you listed above are correct. In summary, a developer would:

1. Use the BigQuery API's "[Jobs: insert](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert)" method to insert a data Extraction job - this results in the data being sent to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
2. Use the Google Cloud Storage API's "[Objects: get](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get#examples)" method to download the file locally.
3. For extra credit, I would query the original BQ table using the "[Tables: get](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource)" method to get the original BigQuery table schema, and use this to build the schema for the MySQL import step.

**The WEB UI method**

Why not just run whatever query you need using the Google BigQuery Web UI, then export the data into a Google Cloud Storage bucket via the UI? Why do you need to use Python?

Comment: It is sort of a test-tasks for people to understand that i have some python skills :) However, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: **Edit: Updated original answer** Ok - then yes, the steps you listed above are correct. In summary, you would: 1. Use the BigQuery API's "Job: insert" method to insert a data Extraction job - this results in the data being sent to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.  2. Use the Google Cloud Storage API's "Objects: get" method to download the file locally. 3. For extra credit, I would query the original BQ table using the "Tables: get" method to get the original BigQuery table schema, and use this to build the schema for the MySQL import step.

Comment: Great! This means I am about right :) One last thing. Do i need to pay anything in order to enable the Google Storage Bucket????? I can not figure out a free way to get access to it

Comment: Ok, it seems that i need to pay for that storage and i do not have anything for that right now. Currently i'm just writing the output of the jobs -> query -> execute into a local csv file. Not sure it is the best way, but at least it is something. What do you think?

Comment: BigQuery results create a new table, and creates pages of data when the result size goes over 10Mb. So, you could query the table, then use paging to save each page of results in a local CSV file: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945399/paginating-bigquery