# How do I paginate the bigquery data using PHP bigquery client library?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am using this php client library to pull the BigQuery data. 
(https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-bigquery )

The issue is that I am not able to paginate the BigQuery data.
Here is how I pulled the data. The link clear shows how we can pull data but does not give any information on paginating the data.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paginating BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945399/paginating-bigquery)

Answer (score 1):

Pagination docs are elsewhere

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#bigquery_browse_table-php

Basically the code will be:

```
$maxResults = 10;
$startIndex = 0;

$options = [
    'maxResults' => $maxResults,
    'startIndex' => $startIndex
];
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($tableId);
$numRows = 0;
foreach ($table->rows($options) as $row) {
    print('---');
    foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
        printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
    }
    $numRows++;
}
```

Comment: Hello Pentium10,

I have tried this answer. This code is not useful when there are around 600000 data. Here, pagination happens automatically in the Google Cloud Client Library for PHP using the generator function rows, which fetches the next page of results during iteration.